# Date time format convert in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm getting date-time from a source as 20110731183330. I want to convert it to '7/31/2011 06:33:30 PM'. Is there a one line code for the same in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim result As Date = Date.ParseExact(dt, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

then we can format it as required.

Answer (score 4):

That would be:

```
Dim result As Date = Date.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Comment: Followed by: Dim formattedDate As String = result.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

Answer (score 0):

It can be...

```
Dim CustomDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(yourdate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```